# CMS Connect Personalization

Tags: experience-cloud, cms-connect

We are attempting to "Personalize" the header & footer from AEM using CMS Connect.

There is a document [Personalize Your External CMS Content](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/cms/guide/cms-connect-personalization.html), which seems to imply that Salesforce will load a page from AES (the [CMS Connect Page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/cms/guide/cms-connect-personalization-connector.html)) and send a URL request parameter containing information `clientContext` (—IP address, language, country, state, city, latitude, and longitude). Still, this information is NOT specific to the individual user who is logged in.

Is there a better way to figure out details about the logged-in user? Something like the Canvas App Context?